# How do I add a "Loading" view controller before my tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to have a "Loading" view controller before my tableView loads. Can you recommend the best way of doing this and if possible provide some code.

Ideally the loading screen will have an activity indication and a label that says loading.

Add a UIView above UITableView.

[image]

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to present some other view on top of your tableview till it loads?

Comment: your question is not enough specified. Are you retrieving data from server so thats why you need to display a loading while downloading data?

Comment: Sorry. Yes I'm downloading an xml and parsing it. While this is happening I want the user to see a screen that has an activity indication on it.

Answer (score 5):

First define these in your .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *loadingView;
```

Then in your `viewWillAppear`, before you begin loading in your table views data, make and display the view:

```
if(!_loadingView)
{
    _loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [loadingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *actInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [actInd setFrame:CGRectMake((loadingView.frame.size.width / 2 - 10), (loadingView.frame.size.height / 2 - 10), 20, 20)];

    UILabel *lblLoading = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((_loadingView.frame.size.width / 2 - 30), (_loadingView.frame.size.height / 2 - 5), 60, 30)];
    lblLoading.text = @"Loading";

    // you will probably need to adjust those frame values to get it centered    

    [loadingView addSubview:actInd];
    [loadingView addSubview:lblLoading];

    [actInd startAnimating];
} 

[_yourTableView addSubview:_loadingView];
```

Then when you are finished loading your data:

```
[_loadingView removeFromSuperView];
```

If your using Storyboard... simply drag a `UIView` onto your `UIViewController`, making sure its layered above the `UITableView`(it does not need to be a subview of the `UITableView`). Drag your `UIActivityIndicatorView` and `UILabel` on, then create an outlet for the `UIView`.

Then in your `viewWillAppear`

```
[_loadingView setHidden NO];
```

Then when your done loading

```
[_loadingView setHidden YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more like it. I'll give it a try!

Comment: If you are using storyboard you could create the UIView & design it easier there as well.. In that case you would just toggle the hidden property on the view instead of adding/removing from the view.

Comment: You mean create the UIView ontop of the tableview controller?

Comment: I added some info to my answer for Storyboard

Comment: That seems a much better way of doing it. I cannot put my UIView in front of my tableView. See screenshot above. Is that because its going a tableViewController and not a normal viewController.

Comment: Yes its because it is a UITableViewController. I would make it a normal UIViewController and just add the tableview separately, just be sure to connect the delegate & datasource

Comment: I've done exactly as you suggested. However the UIView does not appear, just the tableview.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). You display your view and show the loading indicator. Then in a backthread, load your data. When it has finished, update you datasourse, refresh your tableview, and dismiss the loading indicator.

Comment: I don't want to use MBProgreessHUB as its more of a pop up. I would like the loading screen to have a grey background, an activity indicator and a lable saying loading

Comment: just add a UIView all above your table view with a grey background color, and dismiss it with the MBProgreessHUB

Comment: That sounds exactly what I need. But how do I do that. I'm using storyboards

Comment: In the view controller managing your view, add the grey view in the method `-(void)viewDidLoad` and the the MBProgressHUB.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [UIRefreshControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html) as a nice way to do this natively.

Comment: That's no what I want. I want it to say loading and have an activity indicator before my table view loads

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch the loading of your table view to another thread. Now present the 'loading' view (view not view controller). Once your loading on the other thread ends, dismiss the 'loading' view.